# convert bind into delegate in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to convert bind function into delegate **but I want to change so that the event will be triggered on new elements added to the page after initial page load.** How can I change it?

I want to change this code

```
$(".user").bind("mouseenter", fnShowUserHover);
```

Comment: By reading the jQuery docs.  But you really should use `.on` instead, if you have it.

Comment: Just a note, if you are using jquery 1.7, [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) has been superseded by [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: It's a question of preference, if you prefer to be more explicit that you are delegating an event, you can use `.delegate` just fine. See http://forum.jquery.com/topic/delegate-vs-on#14737000002878044

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).delegate(".user", "mouseenter", fnShowUserHover);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use on():

```
$("body").on("mouseenter", ".user", fnShowUserHover);
```

(instead of `body` just choose a common parent for `.user` elements)

with [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) you could specifically write

```
$("body").delegate(".user", "mouseover", fnShowUserHover);
```

Comment: I want to use delegate not bind or on. Please read my question again thanks

Comment: see my edit, but on() is recommended if you're using a recent jquery version as you can read on the doc page

Answer (score 1):

if you are using .on() to delegate

```
$('parentelement').on('mouseenter','.user',fnShowUserHover);
```

or .delegate()

```
$('parentelement').delegate('.user','mouseenter',fnShowUserHover);
```